# Join 3 tables to get single row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to join multiple table to  get single row result for each id. This result will be send to angular UI

I have 3 tables `user`, `friends` and `trip`
A `user` can have multiple `friends` but one `trip`

I like to get all details corresponding to a user in one row, probably `friends` as field like an array?

This is how my table looks.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0879d/2

https://gist.github.com/tomalex0/9dee4fff85583732e7d0

Comment: Show the expected result please.

Comment: How the tables are related ? for example `user` and `friend` how do you know who is whose friend ?

Comment: id in `user` table is same as `user_id` in friends and trip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat` should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT    u.*, t.*, friendlist
FROM      user u
LEFT JOIN trip t ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (name, '- ', email)) friendlist
           FROM     friends
           GROUP BY user_id) f ON f.user_id = u.id
```